# Can we name a package or class as 'main' in java?

Tags: java

Can we name a package or class as 'main' in java? If no, then why not? since 'main' is not a keyword in java.

Comment: Did you try? Did it work? If it worked, then yes, if not then no. The reason? What does the compiler say?

Comment: It is not something you "can't" do but in most cases it is not recomended because you aim name package names, methods, and classes descriptively, and also you are trying to keep within the bounds of Java Naming Conventions.
In other words, you can and there is nothing stoping you but it break Java Naming Conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can give as name any valid identifier..
**main** fulfill that criteria and doens't belong to the java [reserved key words](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

You will break name conventions, but for sure you can..

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all straight answer to your yes or no is Yes you can name any package or class as "main"

Have a look at my code

```
import main.*;
class main
    {
    int a=5;
    public static void main(String string[])
            {
            System.out.println("This is main");
            main mainObject = new main();
            System.out.println(mainObject.a);
            }
    }
```

Explanations to your queries :

Line 1 : I have made a package and imported it : No error from compiler to this

Line 2 : I have made a class with name "main" no errors

Line 8 : I have made reference of class main named it "mainObject" and called constructor too which is "main()". Even here,the syntax "main()" which is constructor of class main which is very similar to the syntax of main method I have not get any kind of error even here.

So I think you can use main to your queries.
All the best.